# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, ubuntu-11.10

while trying to do Unit Testing with Zend Framework I executed the command

```
sudo  phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```

and got this error

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
```

Comment: Looks like something is not in your include_path, that's what usually fires these kinds of errors.

Comment: What version of PHPUnit do you have installed? (`phpunit --version`) PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter is no longer referenced by `/usr/bin/phpunit` in 3.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your install of phpunit did not contain all the dependent packages, like `PHP_CodeCoverage`.

Perhaps try something like:

```
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

More details at [PHPUnit installation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/installation.html) page of the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your pear is too old.

See if the following tip can solve the issue:
http://www.giocc.com/installing-phpunit-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal.html